# reduction the number of "of"s in a sentence

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I have below sentence that contains many "of"s. How to reduce the number of "of"s without missing the original meaning?

> The investigation of the effect of the value of a variable on the function has motivated us to give B=A^2.

Comment: Out of context this isn't really making sense. I  think in  context it might be tough too. It seems reversed. A variable has an effect on the value output by a function. It's odd to characterize it the other way around. I would make this clear without worrying about repeating "of". The trick there is possessives. "value of a function" = "function's value".

Comment: I thought that " 's" is belongs just to creatures.

Comment: @jimm101, you are right. the sentence must be reversed (between variable and function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

> Investigating the effect of changing the variable's value on the function has motivated us to give B=A^2.

Comment: If I were writing that thought I would not talk about value at all. I don't see why you can't just say: "the function's response to the variable moved us to give..."

Answer (score 0):

If I am to understand the statement correctly, the line of thinking expressed is somewhat complicated.

The "**effect**" and "**value**" are both properties of the **variable** (*belong to the variable*). This same "**variable**" is also part of the **function** (*belongs to the function*).

The original string of *prepositional phrases*:

> "The investigation **of the effect of the value of a variable on its
>   function** has motivated..."

can be reworded using *possessives instead*:

> "Investigating a/the **variable's value effect on it's function** has motivated...".

Comment: So sorry I had made a mistake and corrected it recently. the function and variable must be exchanged (due to the jim101's comment)

Answer (score 0):

> The investigation of the effect of the value of a variable on the function has motivated us to give B=A^2.

The word "of" indicates possession. By that token, you could invert the whole set to provide attribution in a different way.

> The investigation of the **variable value's effect** on the function has motivated us to give B=A^2.

Think of this change as the difference between these two:

> Doug's dog.
>   The dog of Doug.